# jQuery UL Tabs duplicate navigation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a jQuery ul basic tabs set up fine.. ( [this one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) )

Is there anyway to duplicate the main tab navigation? For the purpose of say having it at the bottom styled differently?

Works the same as the main tab nav though, selects a different tab has an active class etc.

Just separate, so 2 navs that control one lot of tab content areas.

Possible?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though you could clone the actual navigation bar (see below) but the plugin caches the anchor tags so the cloned navigation does not fully work.

A possible solution is to create a new navigation by cloning the anchors (without events and data, just the markup) and call the "**[select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select)**" method when clicking those anchors to change the tabs:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    create: function(e, ui) {
        var bottomNav = $('<div class="ui-tabs-nav bottom" />').appendTo(this);
        $(this).find('.ui-tabs-nav a')
            .clone()
            .click(function() {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs('select', $(this).index());
            }).appendTo(bottomNav);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ApK3F/)**

---

<s>Yes you can. You can use the [create event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-create) that is fired when the markup for the tabs has been created. Make a deep clone (with data and events) with [**.clone(true, true)**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the `.ui-tabs-nav` element and append to the tabs container (you can use css to change the styling):</s>

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    create: function(e, ui) {
        var tabsNav = $(this).find('.ui-tabs-nav').clone(true, true);
        tabsNav.appendTo(this);
    }
});​
```